# x-ui доступен только локально, но не из интернета

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, vpn, firewall

Установил на облачный сервер x-ui отсюда https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mhsanaei/3x-ui/master/install.sh, задал логин, пароль и порт 59599. На vps в фаерволе открыл 59599 tcp на вход и выход.
systemctl показывает, что процесс запущен. Сам x-ui тоже показывает что успешно запущен, конфиг применился.

Проблема: недоступна веб-морда x-ui снаружи по адресу http://*public_server_ip*:59599
На сервере netstat тоже показывает, что веб-морда доступна только локально. Логи x-ui это подтверждают:

```
Sep 22 10:55:15 ubuntu-vpn-server /usr/local/x-ui/x-ui[273603]: INFO - web server run http on [::]:59599
```

В чем может быть дело и как это поправить?

Comment: По IPv4 или IPv6 пытаетесь подключиться?

Comment: И так и так. Но я видел в мануалах что должен быть доступен по ipv4 снаружи, даже если в логах пишет как в моем случае: по ipv6 и только локально.